# MongoDB - How to search with multiple conditions under nested objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking for a way to search a collection to filter the following data to find the groups that include classes (101, 102, 103); and quantities of 101 and 102 are less than 100. Thank you in advance.

```
[
  {
    "group": "1",
    "classes": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "quantity": "100",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "quantity": "24",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "103",
        "quantity": "10",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "104",
        "quantity": "16",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "105",
        "quantity": "25",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "106",
        "quantity": "20",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "107",
        "quantity": "24",
        "type": "AAA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "2",
    "classes": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "quantity": "20",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "quantity": "30",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "113",
        "quantity": "100",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "114",
        "quantity": "16",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "115",
        "quantity": "20",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "116",
        "quantity": "20",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "117",
        "quantity": "80",
        "type": "AAA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "3",
    "classes": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "quantity": "60",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "quantity": "240",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "103",
        "quantity": "1",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "104",
        "quantity": "16",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "105",
        "quantity": "2",
        "type": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "id": "106",
        "quantity": "20",
        "type": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "id": "107",
        "quantity": "240",
        "type": "AAA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you storing `quantity` as string or number? If you store it as string, you should consider why do that.

Comment: I can store it however I want, but didn't know it would make difference. Consider it as which is easier and faster for the hardware then please.

Answer (score 1):

The query requires aggregation operators, to use it, you need the `$expr` operator.

The filtered documents are required to match both conditions:

1. The documents need to contain `classes.id` with the values of "101", "102", "103" by intersection and validate the returned result is not an empty array.
2. The documents need to have at least one item in the `classes` array which fulfills the `id` in `["101", "102"]` array, and the `quantity` (need to convert to number) is lesser than 100.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $ne: [
          {
            $setIntersection: [
              "$classes.id",
              [
                "101",
                "102",
                "103"
              ]
            ]
          },
          []
        ]
      },
      {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$classes",
              cond: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$this.id",
                      [
                        "101",
                        "102"
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lt: [
                      {
                        $toInt: "$$this.quantity"
                      },
                      100
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TVlRlYsOUNV)